# Exception when editing a control that apparently does not require an Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I am attempting to change the Text property on a control from another thread. I am using this method to do this:

```
        public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, MethodInvoker action)
        {
            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                try
                {
                    control.Invoke(action);
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
                catch (InvalidAsynchronousStateException) { }
            }
            else
            {
                action();
            }
        }
```

I am still getting a `'System.InvalidOperationException'` exception when using this method. When I break into this, I can see that `control.InvokeRequired` is `false`, but it looks like it is in fact being accessed from another thread ??

In the actual error message, it doesn't give me the same of the control that I am trying to invoke. Rather, it gives me the form in which the control resides, stating `'Form1 accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on'.`

I have trying passing the form to the `InvokeIfRequired` method, but still `Form1.InvokeRequired` is `false` and the exception occurs. The control I am trying to invoke was created in the designer.

Here is the code I am using to edit the control:

```
        private void StartUpdateThreads()  // called from the Form ctor
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.TimeUpdater)).Start();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.AccountBalanceUpdater)).Start();
        }

        private void TimeUpdater()
        {
            while (!this.IsDisposed)
            {
                Utilities.InvokeIfRequired(this, (MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {
                        this.timestampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    }));
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
        }
```

Here is the call stack:

```
    MyApp.exe!MyApp.MyAppToolbar.TimeUpdater.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 133 + 0x41 bytes 
    MyApp.exe!MyApp.Utilities.InvokeIfRequired(System.Windows.Forms.Control control, System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker action) Line 34 + 0xb bytes 
    MyApp.exe!MyApp.MyAppToolbar.TimeUpdater() Line 131 + 0x49 bytes
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_InternalHandle()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_CreateParams()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.get_CreateParams()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SizeFromClientSize(Int32 width, Int32 height)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SizeFromClientSize(Size clientSize)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetBordersAndPadding()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetPreferredSizeCore(Size proposedConstraints)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_PreferredSize()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.AdjustSize()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Label.set_Text(String value)\r\n   
    at MyApp.MyAppToolbar.<TimeUpdater>b__0() in PATH\\TO\\FILE.cs:line 133\r\n   
    at MyApp.Utilities.InvokeIfRequired(Control control, MethodInvoker action) in PATH\\TO\\FILE.cs:line 34\r\n  MyApp.MyAppToolbar.TimeUpdater() in PATH\\TO\\FILE.cs:line 131\r\n   
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n   
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Could someone point me in the right direction here ?

Comment: Strange, are you sure that exactly the code inside `InvokeIfRequired` caused an exception? Could you please post the actual stack trace from the exception (including `InnerException`s)?

Comment: Hi Vlad, I have added a stack trace - there is no inner exception present. Thanks

Comment: Using InvokeRequired like this is an anti-pattern.  It creates the dangerous illusion that this code takes care of threading requirements.  It doesn't, it hides a nasty race condition that occurs when the form is closed but the thread keeps running.  Nothing good happens when InvokeRequired returns false.  Which you should use to throw an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @Sherlock: Reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) on `InvokeRequired` you can see that it return false when the control's handle hasn't been created yet. The documentation states that you need to check the value of [`IsHandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated.aspx) before. And there's an issue on the destruction time as well, as Hans states above.

Comment: @Vlad - thank you so much. This actually makes sense as I was previously starting the background process in the forms OnLoad. For some reason I moved it to the constructor, no idea what I was thinking. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sherlock: glad that that helped; I'll move the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation on [`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) you can see that it returns `false` when the control's handle hasn't been created yet. The documentation states that you need to check the value of [`IsHandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated.aspx) before.

And there's an issue on the destruction time as well, as Hans states above, so you might want to check if the control is already disposed when *inside* the correct thread.

Another approach would be to start the background threads when the controls are fully loaded, but again this makes `InvokeIfRequired` not a general-purpose tool.

Answer (score 0):

Hi sherlock i think  this will be helpfull
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx